# handling multiple tabs with hashbang

Tags: javascript, cookies, fragment-identifier

I have a single page app that can have multiple tabs open with each tab doing different actions. if a user hits refresh or back, however, they lose everything they were working on. Is there a way, possibly with a combination of hash-bangs and cookies, to prevent the loss? for example, if the user was to refresh, all the tabs they were using would be opened back up.

Comment: No particular reason to have to use cookies, you could also use localStorage...?

Comment: has to work with all browsers. HTML5 is not an option

Comment: That'd be great to mention in the question next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend against cookies, since they create an unnecessary overhead to the HTTP requests.

[`AmplifyJS`](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) provides cross-browser support for persistent data, using `localStorage` where possible, with fallbacks to `sessionStorage`, `globalStorage` and `userData` (IE).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the `onbeforeunload` event. This event is called (as the name suggests) just before the user "unloads" (refresh/redirect/etc.) the page and it allows you to warn the user  that he's trying to get away from a page with unsaved data.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var warning = 'You\'ve made changes to this page. Are you sure you don\'t want to save them?';

  if(e) {
    e.returnValue = warning;
  }

  return warning;
}
```

See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) for a more detailed overview of the event.

There's plenty of ways to save the data, such as `localStorage`, `IndexedDB`, `AJAX` to a server and (lastly) `Cookies`.